# "TransformerException: A location step was expected" in android xpath

Tags: android, xml, xpath

Ive been trying to pull data from an xml file but i keep getting this error and im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
10-23 14:20:29.250: WARN/System.err(3541): --------------- linked to ------------------
10-23 14:20:29.250: WARN/System.err(3541): javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.
```

Here is my code:

```
String pill;

        URL url = new URL("file:///mnt/sdcard/cpdata/cpxml.xml");
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


        pill = xpath.evaluate("//data/monday/p1/",xml);
        pills.add(pill);
        Log.d("PILLLLLLSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS", pill);
        tv.setText(pill + "hi");
```

And this is my xml document:

```
-<data> 
  -<monday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
  </monday> 
  -<tuesday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
  </tuesday> 
  -<wednesday> 
    <p1>1.0</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
</wednesday> 
-<thursday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
</thursday> 
-<friday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
</friday> 
-<saturday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
</saturday> 
-<sunday> 
    <p1>test1</p1> 
    <p2>test1</p2> 
</sunday>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The isssue is obvious**:

> pill = xpath.evaluate("//data/monday/p1/",xml);

**The XPath expression used**:

```
    data/monday/p1/
```

ends with `"/"` and thus is syntactically illegal.

**Use**:

```
  pill = xpath.evaluate("//data/monday/p1",xml);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it must be something simple i just couldn't figure out what.